# Excel Add-in: How to implement sheet protection event listener?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins

I would like to listen to changes to sheet protection. Current implementation is a recurring thread that checks sheet.ProtectContents. There is a limitation to this implementation while a goal seek function is running.

Any other way to handle change protection event? Even like a button click listener to protect sheet dialog.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? You could add a `Worksheet Change()` event that checks to see if the protection is changed. Maybe need to set a global (shudder) variable on worksheet open to see what the setting is, and if after a change, the protection is different...

Comment: Worksheet change doesn't get triggered on Protect/Unprotect sheet. only triggers when a value in a cell changes.